# How to define a Pandas column as a list

Tags: pandas, list, keras

I'm using Keras Image Data Generator for data augmentation, and the flow_from_dataframe function within it. Info regarding it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe

```
# Create new dataframes for train and test

df_train = pd.DataFrame()
df_train['image'], df_train['labels'] = X_train, y_train

df_test = pd.DataFrame()
df_test['image'], df_test['labels'] = X_test, y_test
```

**This is what one dataframe looks like:**

```
image   labels
4227  /Users/m/Documents/Machine Learning Pr...  [73, 0]
4676  /Users/m/Documents/Machine Learning Pr...  [36, 0]
800   /Users/m/Documents/Machine Learning Pr...  [26, 0]
3671  /Users/m/Documents/Machine Learning Pr...  [42, 0]
```

**This is how I've imported the data generator:**

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    rotation_range = 40,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    fill_mode = 'nearest'
    )

test_datagen= ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe = df_train,
x_col="image",
y_col="labels",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode='multi_output',
target_size=(128, 128))


valid_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe = df_test,
x_col = "image",
y_col = "labels",
batch_size = 32,
seed = 42,
shuffle = True,
class_mode='multi_output',

target_size=(128, 128))
```

The function reads in a dataframe, but in the documentation it says the y_col specified must be a list:

> y_col string or list, column/s in dataframe that has the target data.

Before I created the dataframe the column was a list, but now that it's a column in pandas it's no longer classed as a 'list', right? So why do I get this error message:

```
TypeError: If class_mode="multi_output", y_col must be a list. Received str.
```

I want to use the class mode multi outputas above, and it states y_col must be a list but it's a string. Not sure why it is stating it's a string? Is there anyway to change the 'type' of a column **within** a dataframe or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: In the function `test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe` you specified `class_mode='multi_output'` and `y_col = "labels"`. So, `y_col` is a string not a list, which leads to the TypeError. Modifie `y_col` to provide a list instead.

Comment: I thought that too but the function test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe says to specify the dataframe separately and y_col to be the 'name of the column' i.e. rather than list(df_train['labels']) it should just be 'labels' as you specify the dataframe as a parameter earlier.

Comment: Exactly, `y_col` is either the name of the columns (if string) or the list of the name of all columns used as y. Since you specified `class_mode = "multi_ouput"`, you need to specify not one column but multiple of them through a list of names

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the issue. I was totally misreading what it meant by columns and getting confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'List' here means list of column names.

As Zelemist has said, change your dataframe so that there are two columns rather than the one you have.

Then input a list to y_col such as:

```
y_col = ['col1', 'col2]
```

Hope it makes sense now.